# pushing signed docker images to GCR

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

Somewhat of a GCR newbie question.

I have not been able to find any documentation on whether it is possible to push signed docker images to GCR. So I attempted it but it fails with following error below. 
I first built a docker image, then tagged it to point to my project in GCR with "docker tag  gcr.io/my-project/image-name:tag"
Then attempted signing using 
"docker trust sign gcr.io/my-project/image-name:tag"

Error: error contacting notary server: denied: Token exchange failed for project 'gcr.io:my-project'. Please enable Google Container Registry API in Cloud Console at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=gcr.io:my-project before performing this operation.

GCR API for my project is enabled and I have permissions to push to it.

Do I need to something more in my project in GCP to be able to push signed images OR it is just not supported?

If later, how does one (as a image consumer) verify the integrity of the image?

thanks, 
J

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported in Google Cloud Platform.

You can file a feature request to request its implementation [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

To verify an images integrity, use [image digests](https://engineering.remind.com/docker-image-digests/). Basically they are cryptographic hashes associated with the image. You can compare the hash of the image you pulled with the hash you are expecting. Command reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/)

Answer (score 1):

Google now implements the concept of Binary Authorization and "attestations" based off of [Kritis](https://github.com/grafeas/kritis/blob/master/docs/binary-authorization.md). The intention is for this to be used within your CI/CD pipeline to ensure images have been created and validated correctly.

[Full docs are here](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/overview) but the process basically consists of signing an image via a PKIX signature and then using the `gcloud` tool to create an attestation.

You then specify a [Binary Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/setting-up) policy on your GKE cluster to enforce which attestations are required before an image is allowed to be used within the cluster.